# Repeatedly fread() 16 bits from binary file

Tags: c, file, file-io, binary, hex

I'm reading a binary file.  The first 16 bits represent an array index, the next 16 represent the number of 16-bit items about to be listed, and then the remaining multiples of 16 represent all those 16-bit items.  For example, the following hex-dump of the file 'program':

```
 30 00 00 02 10 00 F0 25
```

represents index 0x3000, with 0x0002 elements following, which are 0x1000 and 0xF025.

```
 FILE *fp = fopen(program, "rb");
 char indexChar, nItemsChar;
 u_int16_t index, nItems;
 fread (&indexChar, 2, 1, fp);
 fread (&nItemsChar, 2, 1, fp);
 address = strtol(&indexChar, NULL, 16);
 nItems = strtol(&nItemsChar, NULL, 16);
 for (u_int16_t i = 0; i < nItems; ++i)
 {
     fread (state->mem + index + i, 2, 1, fp);
 }
```

I'm not even sure if this approach works because I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to fRead() into nItemsChar.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: open it with binary mode `rb'. and the read size is sizeof(u_int16_t) counting 1 not read size 2 count 1.

Comment: Whoops, it should've been 'rb'.  But yeah, it's still happening, even with that change.

Comment: You are reading 2 bytes into chars.  Make indexChar and nItemsChar char[2].

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing ascii (text) file i/o and binary.

- Program is crashing at fread(&nItemsChar,2,1,fp) because you have read 2 bytes into a 1 byte memory space (actually it may be messing up on the previous fread)
- You then try to use strtol which converts from ascii to long int but the values read are binary

Instead just use

```
fread(&index, sizeof(index),1,fp);
fread(&nItems, sizeof(nItems),1,fp);
```

and then the for loop.  Note that this assumes that the file is written with the same endianness as your processor/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint16_t index, *nItems;

fread (&index, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, fp);
nItems = (uint16_t*)calloc(index, sizeof(uint16_t));
fread (nItems, sizeof(uint16_t), index, fp);
```